# Should I expect the same or lower water pressure when increasing pipe size for a shower?

Tags: water-pressure

I'm remodeling my shower with 2 body sprays, a hand held sprayer and maintaining the standard shower head.  Currently I have 1/2" pipes and the new fixtures require 3/4" pipes.  Should I expect the same or lower water pressure with the 3/4" pipes?

Only replacing what's needed for the install. Same wall, so the runs will probably be 2-3 feet. I have a contractor that will complete the installation. Planning to start demo and rough in next week. I'm asking to know what to expect.

Makes sense, I don't plan to use all of the nozzles at once.  Main shower head with body sprays or main shower head with hand held.  Sounds like I should expect some level of water pressure loss when combining nozzles.

Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Are you completely replacing the 1/2" pipes? Are you using reducing adapters?  How long are the runs and where do they originate? Please revise to add detail.

Comment: Please **revise** to add detail. All that belongs in your question, not down here. Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works.

Comment: 1/2 inch piping(main house) usually good for one fixture at a time.  There should be a slight pressure drop with one fixture.  Trying with three or four fixtures at same time, might be left with dribbles.

Comment: Just wondering about the basic hydraulics here... if the amount of water pumped into the house stays the same, larger pipes won't do much will they? The only thing that would matter is more nozzles, that would divide that pressure amongst more exit surface.

Comment: An easy test is turn on shower, turn on sink taps, and flush the toilet and see what pressure you have left.